# How to see failed lambda executions on datadog using lambda proxy integration

Tags: lambda, serverless-framework, datadog

I am kind of new on datadog and was wondering how to show errors for lambda executions that are integrated with API Gateway using the LAMBDA_PROXY integration.

This may sound simple but because of how you need to handle custom errors when using the LAMBDA_PROXY (which basically makes you catch exceptions and return a specific object to API GATEWAY) all lambda executions ends "correctly" on datadog even though many of them return an error object (which means that debugging failed lambda executions is really hard).

Is there a way to show on Datadog that this executions are errors instead of a "green" check for better visibility?. am using the serverless framework with the datadog plugin (`serverless-plugin-datadog`)

(We can try to change the LAMBDA_PROXY to the more raw lambda integration, but that doesnt look right and present a big change in my configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting with datadog's team, they acknowledge that this was in fact a missing feature and create a PR on their github to include it on the 5.3.0 version of the plugin.

You can find the PR details on: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-lambda-python/pull/229

So a simple update of the plugin should be enough to include this behavior on your monitoring.